# What is the purpose of passing an single argument

Tags: php, function, syntax

In the function below, local variable "$redirect_url" already defined inside the function, what is the purpose of passing it as an argument also ?

```
function change_login_destination ( $redirect_url ){
    $redirect_url = '/some-url';
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: It's wrong, you don't need to define any argument for this function or define function like `change_login_destination ( $redirect_url  = '/some-url')`

Comment: If it's never going to change should probably just be a constant.

Comment: Is that the entire function?  If so it seems to lack any real purpose.

Comment: Actually it is a part of filter hook in WP. Next part is: add_filter('login_redirect', 'change_login_destination');

Comment: In this case, it's totally pointless since you immediately overwrite the value. Is there some additional context?

Comment: Nope, that’s the whole function. I was also confused and I thought I was missing something. I guess they made a mistake.